# In JPA, is there any way to insert data in DB in batch and insert only if not exists in DB

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

In JPA, is there any way to insert data in DB in batch and insert only if not exists in DB. When I try to insert in batch, because of the unique key constraint, it throws exception. I want to insert all the records which are not exist in the DB and rest should be skipped.

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not
>   execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint
>   [reference_number_master_id_key]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement

Answer (score 4):

Me and my team ended up creating implementations that our JpaRepositories extend to add such behavior.

Primary Interface

```
public interface BatchInsertable <T> {
    enum Mode {NORMAL, IGNORE, REPLACE}

    void batchInsertUsingMode(Collection<T> items, final Mode mode);
}
```

This is how we hook it up to an existing JpaRepository.

```
public interface UrlRepository extends JpaRepository<UrlEntity, Long>, BatchInsertable<UrlEntity> {
    // insert common methods
}
```

... and it's usage

```
urlRepository.batchInsertUsingMode(newUrlEntities, BatchInsertable.Mode.IGNORE);
```

Batch Inserter implementation

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@Lazy
public class BatchInserter<T> extends AbstractBaseBatchJdbcMutation<T> implements BatchInsertable<T> {

    @Override
    public void batchInsertUsingMode(final Collection<T> items, final Mode mode) {
        final Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("MODE", mode == Mode.IGNORE ? "INSERT IGNORE" : mode == Mode.REPLACE ? "REPLACE" : "INSERT");
        parameters.put("STAGING_TABLE", getTableName());
        parameters.put("COLUMNS", buildColumnNameList());
        parameters.put("PLACEHOLDERS", buildBindVariablePlaceholderList());

        final StrSubstitutor strSubstitutor = new StrSubstitutor(parameters);
        final String sqlTemplate = "${MODE} INTO `${STAGING_TABLE}` (${COLUMNS}) VALUES (${PLACEHOLDERS})";
        getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(strSubstitutor.replace(sqlTemplate), buildBindVariables(items));
    }
}
```

Batch Deleter implementation

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@Lazy
public class BatchDeleter<T> extends AbstractBaseBatchJdbcMutation<T> implements BatchDeletable<T> {

    @Override
    public int batchDelete(final List<T> items) {
        final Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("STAGING_TABLE", getTableName());
        parameters.put("COLUMNS", buildColumnNameList());
        parameters.put("PLACEHOLDERS", buildBindVariablePlaceholderList());

        final StrSubstitutor strSubstitutor = new StrSubstitutor(parameters);
        final String sqlTemplate = "DELETE FROM `${STAGING_TABLE}` WHERE (${COLUMNS}) = (${PLACEHOLDERS})";
        final int[] updateCounts = getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(strSubstitutor.replace(sqlTemplate), buildBindVariables(items));
        return sum(updateCounts);
    }

    private static int sum(final int[] updateCounts) {
        int sum = 0;

        for (final int updateCount : updateCounts) {
            sum += updateCount;
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

An abstract class that maintains common configs binding logic

```
public abstract class AbstractBaseBatchJdbcMutation<T> {
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private List<ColumnValueExtractors> columnExtractors;

    private String tableName;

    public void setColumnExtractors(final List<ColumnValueExtractors> columnExtractors) {
        this.columnExtractors = new ArrayList<>(columnExtractors);
    }

    public void setTableName(final String tableName) {
        this.tableName = tableName;
    }

    protected List<Object[]> buildBindVariables(final Collection<T> items) {
        return FluentIterable.from(items).transform(new BulkBindingTransform<T>(columnExtractors)).toList();
    }

    protected JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

    protected String getTableName() {
        return tableName;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(final DataSource datasource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(datasource);
    }

    protected String buildColumnNameList() {
        return join(extract(columnExtractors, on(ColumnValueExtractors.class).getColumnName()), ",");
    }

    protected String buildBindVariablePlaceholderList() {
        return join(nCopies(columnExtractors.size(), "?"), ",");
    }

    private static class BulkBindingTransform<T> implements Function<T, Object[]> {

        private final List<ColumnValueExtractors> columns;
        private BulkBindingTransform(final List<ColumnValueExtractors> columns) {
            this.columns = columns;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public Object[] apply(final T input) {
            final Object[] bindings = new Object[columns.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++) {
                bindings[i] = columns.get(i).resolveValue(input);
            }

            return bindings;
        }

    }
}
```

This will let you also bypass some of the slowness you may encounter directly interfacing with the default `save(Iterable<S> iterable)` interface. We use it all over for batch SQL operations. It is amazing how complicated such a simple task is. My bet is that you can trim this down to meet your specific needs. :)

Comment: Very informative answer. However this does not use JPA features does it ? Isn't this more of Spring JDBC template ? Anyway, this should suffice as a solution for OP. When we deal it the JPA/Hibernate way, we need to worry about flushing caches etc to avoid memory issues.

Comment: Agreed. It plays nicely with JPA but I am not aware of a way to do it in pure JPA or purely with Hibernate. Which is why we created this beast :) I would be VERY happy to find a simpler alternative.